# Unable to pick up properties file while running weblogic or tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic

I am trying to pick up the properties file through ResourceBundle as below.

```
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);   
ResourceBundle system = ResourceBundle
    .getBundle("system",Locale.getDefault(),loader);
```

But I am getting the below exception.
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name system, locale en_US

I have kept the properties file in src folder. I have checked the classes folder also. The path of the properties file is same in classes and src folder. Please assist on this....

Comment: in which folder have you placed the properties file and what is it called?

Comment: just make sure that the system.properties file is directly under the WEB-INF\class folder

Comment: btw why dont you use this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)

Answer (score 1):

Your call requires a class

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
public class system_en_US extends ResourceBundle {

  @Override
  public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }
}
```

(in the default package). `system` is an uncommon name for a class, so maybe it is just missing.

Second, your providing a custom classloader. So the `system.class` has to be found at one of the urls.